# Компиляция проекта в CodeBlocks[Не запускается приложение]

Tags: c++, ide, gcc, компилятор, codeblocks

Дело вот в чем раньшеее всеее рабооооталооо нооормааальноо, а теперь фигня какая-то (переустановка IDE не помогает, винду сносить не вариант)

Собственно о проблеме: Создаю проект пишу код в main.cpp нажимаю на кнопку компиляции запускается консольное приложение и просто мигает курсор на одном месте в этом окне и ничего не происходит абсолютно!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался даже нулевой проект запустить (ну там где просто Hello World! написано) тоже 0 реакции просто мигает курсор.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Самое примечательное что файлики он создает и компилятор не ругается, можно даже перейти к файлу .exe и попробовать запустить, но он даже не запустит консольное окно, а процесс сего действия намертво зависнет в системе и его невозможно завершить никак

P.S Что за ерунда творится и как эту проблему решить, может кто сталкивался с данным приколом?

Comment: Что если попробовать запустить отладку и проверить пошаговое выполнение?

Comment: после включения дебаггера, невозможно его остановить и кнопка для выполнения запуска отладки не работает

Comment: Т.е. новый проект с дефолтным main дает такое поведение? Читайте об этом на сайте codeblocks. Скорее всего что-то в базовых настройках не так, но вслепую угадать тяжело.
Попробуйте скомпилировать исходники без IDE. Удачно?

Comment: @Arkady именно, и где мне читать об этом на сайте?

Comment: @MaximPro, там есть форум.

Comment: никогда не компилировал без ide, что мне нужно написать в консоли для компиляции?

Comment: Для компиляции в консоли самый простой вариант: `g++ main.cpp`

Comment: @alexolut скомпилил, получил .exe, запустил .exe, не запустился .exe, завис намертво в процессах

Comment: Фигня какая-то. Может вирус или антивирус? Могу предложить попробовать поставить Qt со встроенным mingw и повторить всё в нем. Или с CodeBlocks на другой машине. Т.к. поведение оч.странное, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut ну компилятор я отдельно ставил (gcc), но до этого у меня проблема со встроенным компилятором случилась